# Mathematica: Print approximate number using E-notation with specified accuracy

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, what is the easiest way to print a given approximate number using E-notation with a specified accuracy? For example given:

> a = 1.23456789 10^-23

how can **a** be printed to 3 significant digits to get:

> 1.23E-23

Notice that trying FortranForm[] with N[] does not work since N[] will not truncate an approximate number.

Answer (score 1):

After some playing around I found an answer:

> NumberForm[a, {5, 3}, 
>    NumberFormat -> (SequenceForm[#1, "E", #3] &), 
>    ExponentFunction -> (# &)]

If you want to make this more robust and be able to handle rational numbers as well, replace **a** by **N[a,3]** .

Notice that the **ExponentFunction** is needed since a number like 1.2345 would be outputted as **1.23E** .

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`ScientificForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScientificForm.html) with the [`NumberFormat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScientificForm.html) option.

With

```
a = 1.23456789 10^-23;
```

Then

```
ScientificForm[a, 3]
```

> ```
> 1.23*10^(-23)
> ```

The output can be further formatted to you spec with the `NumberFormat` option.

```
ScientificForm[a, 3, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "E", #3}] &)]
```

> ```
> 1.23E-23
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not work with numbers like 1.2345. See my answer for a solution that gets around this.